# Enable GPS programmatically

Tags: javascript, gps, settings

I'm using Javascript to develop my app. So I have a problem. When I start the app I check if GPS or internet connection are enabled. But now my app shows only an alert that say: "GPS is disable".

There is a way to create a button "Go to Setting" to send the user to device settings? Or can I enable gps programmatically?